# How to monitor packets from a MAC address

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, csv, aircrack-ng, airodump-ng

I am wanting to monitor a MAC address for activity on my network using airodump-ng

I am currently:

First running this:

```
airodump-ng mon0 --write t
```

which writes to the file `t-01.csv` a csv with the format:

```
Station MAC, First time seen, Last time seen, Power, # packets, BSSID, Probed ESSIDs
```

then I have a bash script that does this:

```
while [ true ]
do
    t=`cat t-01.csv | grep '30:F1:DA:7B:F3:2C' | cut -d ',' -f5`
    if [[ "$t" != "$lt" ]]
    then
            lt="$t"
            echo "activity"
    fi
done
```

Which is basically watching the MAC address for a change in the `# packets` and when it changes it means there has been some activity. But the `airodump-ng` seems to have an immense lag when writing to a file (around 1-2 seconds) Is there an alternative way to do this, that is faster?

## Found my answer:

https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19737/tcpdump-filter-by-mac-address/19741#19741?newreg=8e32529cbc7c4234b3a062bb655b7e5f

I can then write a script like:

```
#!/bin/bash
tcpdump -i mon0 ether host "30:F1:DA:7B:F3:2C" | while read b; do
    echo "Activity!"
done
```

Comment: I suggest moving your answer into an answer.  It's ok to answer your own question on SE.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of cat-ing the file each time, use:

```
tail -f t-01.csv | grep '30:F1:DA:7B:F3:2C' | cut -d ',' -f5`
```

and the rest of the script is the same.

Comment: does not work. and also does not output anything.

Comment: removed `-f` and still equally as laggy

Comment: It is not to do with the script it is todo with `airodump-ng`s  `--write` which is rubbishly slow vs the GUI